# HIde load more button when all items are from array displayed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

This should be easy but of course I can't figure it out :)

Basically I've implemented a "load more" button when there are more items to display from array but when it reaches the end, I'd like to hide it. The code below doesn't work and I have a feeling it's because it need to check the index of the array and if it's at the end, then hide the button but I am unsure of how to go about the syntax. Thanks

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import releases from "../data/releases.json";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../main.css'

const Release = () => {
  // get first 12 items in array & load next 12 with "see more button"
  const STEP = 12;
  const [items, setItems] = useState(releases.slice(0, STEP));

  const loadMore = () => {
    setItems([...items, ...releases.slice(items.length, items.length + STEP)]);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="release fadein">
        {items.map((item, i) => (
          <div className="item" key={i}>
            <Link to={`/release/${item.id}`}>
              <img src={item.imageURL} alt={item.artist} />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
{/* code that isn't working here */}
        {items ? <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn" > show more </button> : <button className="btn hidden" ></button>}
      </div>
    </Wrapper >
  )
}
```

Comment: There are no more items to load once the items collection is the same size as the releases collection. `{items.length < releases.length && <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn" > show more </button>}` - you do not need an `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the items are less  than 12 the button will not be displayed

```
 {items%12 ===0 ? <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn" > show more </button> : nul}
```

Comment: I think you meant `items.length`.

Anyway, this fails in two cases: When there are 0 items in the original array (releases), and when the items in the original array (releases) are exactly 12.
The button shouldn't show in these cases since there are no items to load.
It's better to compare the lengths of both arrays e.g. `(items.length < releases.length) && <button>show more</button>`.

Comment: I think you meant `items.length`.

Anyway, this fails in two cases: When there are 0 items in the original array (releases), and when the items in the original array (releases) are exactly 12.
The button shouldn't show in these cases since there are no items to load.
It's better to compare the lengths both arrays e.g. `(items.length < releases.length) && <button>show more</button>`.